# Desactivar controles asp.net mvc del lado de servidor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Buen dia, presento una pequeña inquietud, recientemente me encuentro elaborando un módulo de ventas para la empresa a la cual laboro. Lo que requiero es desactivar dos controles al momento de identificar que es una venta de contado:

Controles:

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="solici" onclick="parent.location='../Aspx/Visor/ConstruirReporte.aspx?Reporte=FAC2&id=<%=ViewData["id"]%>    '" value="Solicitud de crédito">

<input type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="aprobe" onclick="parent.location='../Aspx/Factura/DetalleAprobacion.aspx?id=<%=ViewData["id"]%>    '" value="Detalle Aprobacion">
```

he probado con lo siguiente:

```
<% var factura = new MvcApp.Models.factura();

        var idFactura = Convert.ToDecimal(Request.QueryString["id"]);//recoge el parametro del registro
        var numerico = 2;//inicializo la variable en 2, equivale a una venta de contado

     if (factura.id_forma_pago == numerico)//valido
     {
         deshabilitarcontroles();//llamo al metodo 
     }}

   public void deshabilitarcontroles()
        {
            solici.Visible = false;//indicó funciones
            aprobe.Visible = false;
        }
     %>
```

Mi inquietud es que no me reconoce los id de cada control, que instruccion debo indicarle para cumplir mi objetivo.

-> De Antemano Gracias!

Comment: Y no es mas fácil usando javascript?

Comment: como lo harias?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que defines son input de html y no web controles de asp.net, o sea

```
<asp:Button
```

Para accederlos desde el servidor debes poner el `runat="server"` entonces tendras html controls

[HTML Input Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s7csdtts.aspx)

```
<input type="button" runat="server" class="btn btn-primary" id="solici"
```

con lo cual podrias usar

```
solici.Visible = false;
```

Si se trata de un proyecto `asp.net mvc` se podria ocultar el control usando

```
<%if (factura.id_forma_pago != numerico){%>
    <input type="button" runat="server" class="btn btn-primary" id="solici" 
<%}%>
```

condicionas el html para que se renderice el input o no

Comment: Hola @Leandro gracias por responder a mi duda y me queda claro en que fallaba, no he logrado mi objetivo al parecer por un evento que indico en ese boton y es fundamental. A lo cual me genera este error `Las etiquetas de servidor no pueden contener construcciones <% ... %>`

Comment: que tipo de desarrollo estas realizando? porque ahora que veo ViewData es de asp.net mvc, pero no mencionaste nada de mvc imagine se trata de asp.net clasico

Comment: es correcto, incluyo el `ViewData` para acceder al registro, los button los empleo ya sea para redirigir a un form o para mostrar algunos informes

Comment: lo que requiero hacer es básicamente que cuando ese registro pertenezca a una venta de contado deshabilitar ese control, pero se presenta el inconveniente que cuando declaro `<%=ViewData["id"]%>` no puedo accesar los id definidos para cada control

Comment: pero entonces se trata de un desarrollo asp.net mvc ?

Comment: es correcto @Leandro

Comment: per entonces eso del visible que quieres asignar no aplica, debes ocutarlo usando style o sino codigo condicional

Comment: edite la respuesta para poner un ejemplo en asp.net mvc, pero deberias mencionarlo y cambiar el tag de la pregunta

Answer (score 2):

No los reconoce porque no tienen la propiedad **runat="server"** que te permiten acceder a los controles desde el **CodeBehind** esto quiere decir que puedes interactuar con sus propiedades desde el lado del servidor, puedes [leer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/k33801s3%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#Controles%20de%20servidor%20Web) un poco sobre lo que hablo.

En tu caso puedes agregar la propiedad a tu `input` o usar el **Control** `Button` de asp de esta manera:

```
<asp:Button ID="solici" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary" Text="Solicitud de crédito" OnClick="parent.location='../Aspx/Visor/ConstruirReporte.aspx?Reporte=FAC2&id=<%=ViewData["id"]%>'" />
<asp:Button ID="aprobe" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-success" Text="Detalle Aprobacion" OnClick="parent.location='../Aspx/Factura/DetalleAprobacion.aspx?id=<%=ViewData["id"]%>'" />
```

Y en el **CodeBehind**:

```
public void deshabilitarcontroles()
{
   solici.Visible = false;
   aprobe.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: He incluido la propiedad tal y como me los has indicado y le agradezco por compartir la información, pero aun no los reconoce

Comment: **<input type="button" runat="server" ... />** así lo colocaste?

Comment: `<input type="button" runat="server" class="btn btn-success" id="aprobe" onclick="parent.location='../Aspx/Factura/DetalleAprobacion.aspx?id=<%=ViewData["id"]%>    '" value="Detalle Aprobacion">` de esa manera.

Comment: Ya lo probé en mi código y funciona algo debes estar haciendo mal. `<input type="button" runat="server" class="btn btn-success" id="aprobe" onclick="parent.location='../Aspx/Factura/DetalleAprobacion.aspx?id=<%=ViewData["id"]%> '" value="Detalle Aprobacion" />`

Comment: Arroja que no existe en el contexto actual, tengo mi linea exactamente igual a esa salvo que el id, tiene otro nombre

Comment: Es por el onclick que estas intentando agregar no me lo reconoce cuando agrego esto `onclick="parent.location='../Aspx/Factura/DetalleAprobacion.aspx?id=<%=ViewData["id"]%> '"`

Comment: Compile la solución y hice el proceso y me genera lo siguiente: Las etiquetas de servidor no pueden contener construcciones <% ... %>.